# Git config inside dockerfile using HTTPS? (Azure DevOps)

Tags: git, azure-devops, dockerfile

I'm trying to authenticate with ADO so I can install one of remote requirements for my python app. This is what works locally:

```
RUN git config --global credential.helper 'cache'; echo "protocol=https\n\
host=dev.azure.com\n\
username=${AZURE_USERNAME}\n\
password=${AZURE_PASSWORD}" | \
git credential approve && \
pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip setuptools && \
pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements/requirements-remote.txt
```

However, this uses auto-generated credentials (temporary password). SSH doesn't work in our use case. How do I go about this so I don't have to update my password every single time on pipeline run?

Comment: Why are you trying to inject credentials into a docker image? You should inject them into the environment when the image is used insteadl. Smells like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Linux#create-a-pat) (PAT)

```
MY_PAT=yourPAT # replace "yourPAT" with ":PatStringFromWebUI"
B64_PAT=$(printf "%s"":$MY_PAT" | base64)
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic ${B64_PAT}" clone https://dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoName
```

Comment: Not good, I can't have PAT in plaintext

Comment: I did not figure out that you are building a container. @fredrik is correct, you should pass the PAT as env at runtime (when running the container) or use docker secrets

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add it globally

```
MY_PAT=[YourPAT]
B64_PAT=$(printf "%s"":$MY_PAT" | base64)
git config --global --add http.extraHeader "Authorization: Basic ${B64_PAT}"
```